# How to extract String from a value of column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

There is a column that has value `XYZ|YYYY-MM-DD` and I have to extract this `XYZ` from that column.

`XYZ` has a different value for each row.

Comment: Please, show your current code and describe, what is the issue with it. If you have any errors, post them as plain text.

Comment: Sql Server 2008 has been end of life for a couple years now. That means no more patches... not even critical security updates. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it.

Comment: Is XYZ a placeholder for n characters or is it always 3 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want the first substring before the pipe character.  If so, then just use a basic substring operation:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(col, 1, CHARINDEX('|', col) - 1)
FROM yourTable;
```